# Неполное чтение текста из файла

Tags: c#, файлы, list

При чтении файла и последующих преобразованиях исходные числа из файла в формате string укорачиваются. В самом файле 2 числа с длиной более 50 символов.

Задача относится к теме "алгоритмы длинной арифметики". 
Я пробовал записывать данные в массив и выводить их и получается тот же укороченный результат.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может заключаться проблема?

Листинг кода:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> number1 = (File.ReadAllLines("G:\\subtraction.txt")).ToList();
        File.WriteAllLines("G:\\output_substraction.txt", number1);
        foreach (var s in number1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: А вы дебажить пробовали? Ну, там поставить точку останова на строку записи, и посмотреть сколько элементов прочиталось в `number1` ? Чтоб для начала определить проблемное место.

Comment: @Bulson по циклу foreach проходит 2 раза как и положено, ничего примечательного не заметил. Метод File.ReadAllLines ведь берет строки из файла, поэтому я думаю все правильно.

Comment: Нужно больше информации: покажите что было на входе, что стало на выходе, как укорачиваются, может они у вас "склеиваются" в одно число, т.к. не содержат символа перехода на новую строку между собой?

Comment: @Bulson Проблему решил (хотя и частично), но все равно было бы интересно узнать, почему не работал первый вариант кода.
Насчет исходной информации, то 2 числа находятся в txt файле на первой и второй строке соответственно, разделенных между собой символом перехода на новую строку ('\n').

Comment: @FoggyFinder https://gist.github.com/Ram1L5/ae7afc3bcdf662265c4dff2a7301d94a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема полностью решена. Измененный код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("G:\\subtraction.txt");
    string str; 
    var numbers = new List<string>();

    while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        numbers.Add(str); 
    }
    foreach (var k in numbers)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(k); 
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image: txt-файл]